# Mimic Windows Explorer file copy method using .Net Framework 4.5

Tags: .net, windows, winforms

I have a C# WinForm app using .Net Framework 4.5.2. I have an environment where we have Windows 7 virtual machines. When I plugin a thumb drive Windows will not assign it a drive letter and the thumb drive will be listed in the "Other" category on My Computer.

I can use windows Explorer and click and drag the files into the folder and the files will be copied to the thumb drive. This is the only way I can copy files to the thumb drive.
[image]

The problem is that I can't get it to work using .Net Framework. Since it doesn't have a drive letter I can't use System.IO.File.Copy(). I also tried using Volume Id and windows copy in the command line.

```
System.IO.File.Copy( "a.pdf", System.IO.Path.Combine( @"\\?\Volume{c06fa891-c5a9-11e7-9bc6-f01faf0be092}\", "a.pdf" ) );

copy "a.pdf" "\\?\Volume{c06fa891-c5a9-11e7-9bc6-f01faf0be092}\a.pdf"
```

Both give me the same "The parameter is incorrect." error message so I'm guessing Windows Explorer is not using Volume Ids to copy the file.

[image]

Is it possible to use the method to copy files used by Windows Explorer using .Net Framework?

3/8 Update -. I ran Process Explorer and this was the one thing that relates to thumb drive. After doing some searching I guess this might be WinAPI.

```
Event   \Sessions\1\BaseNamedObjects\##?#STORAGE#Volume#_??_USBSTOR#Disk&Ven_VendorCo&Prod_ProductCode&Rev_2.00#92070841A6386815041&0#{53f56307-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}#{53f5630d-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}
```

Also ran Process Monitor and the logs show that explorer is using \Client\d$ to connect to the thumb drive.

```
3:01:16.1677065 PM  Explorer.EXE    2396    RegQueryKey HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{8DA1D365-1E63-4531-B1DD-824E76DD6F72}\Instance SUCCESS Query: Name
3:01:16.1677234 PM  Explorer.EXE    2396    RegQueryKey HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{8DA1D365-1E63-4531-B1DD-824E76DD6F72}\Instance SUCCESS Query: HandleTags, HandleTags: 0x0
3:01:16.1677382 PM  Explorer.EXE    2396    RegQueryKey HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{8DA1D365-1E63-4531-B1DD-824E76DD6F72}\Instance SUCCESS Query: HandleTags, HandleTags: 0x0
3:01:16.1677580 PM  Explorer.EXE    2396    RegOpenKey  HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{8DA1D365-1E63-4531-B1DD-824E76DD6F72}\Instance\InitPropertyBag SUCCESS Desired Access: Read
3:01:16.1678296 PM  Explorer.EXE    2396    RegQueryKey HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{8DA1D365-1E63-4531-B1DD-824E76DD6F72}\Instance\InitPropertyBag SUCCESS Query: Name
3:01:16.1678500 PM  Explorer.EXE    2396    RegQueryKey HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{8DA1D365-1E63-4531-B1DD-824E76DD6F72}\Instance\InitPropertyBag SUCCESS Query: HandleTags, HandleTags: 0x0
3:01:16.1678694 PM  Explorer.EXE    2396    RegOpenKey  HKCR\CLSID\{8DA1D365-1E63-4531-B1DD-824E76DD6F72}\Instance\InitPropertyBag  NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Maximum Allowed
3:01:16.1678906 PM  Explorer.EXE    2396    RegQueryValue   HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{8DA1D365-1E63-4531-B1DD-824E76DD6F72}\Instance\InitPropertyBag\TargetSpecialFolder NAME NOT FOUND  Length: 144
3:01:16.1679200 PM  Explorer.EXE    2396    RegQueryKey HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{8DA1D365-1E63-4531-B1DD-824E76DD6F72}\Instance\InitPropertyBag SUCCESS Query: Name
3:01:16.1679382 PM  Explorer.EXE    2396    RegQueryKey HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{8DA1D365-1E63-4531-B1DD-824E76DD6F72}\Instance\InitPropertyBag SUCCESS Query: HandleTags, HandleTags: 0x0
3:01:16.1679573 PM  Explorer.EXE    2396    RegOpenKey  HKCR\CLSID\{8DA1D365-1E63-4531-B1DD-824E76DD6F72}\Instance\InitPropertyBag  NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Maximum Allowed
3:01:16.1679755 PM  Explorer.EXE    2396    RegQueryValue   HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{8DA1D365-1E63-4531-B1DD-824E76DD6F72}\Instance\InitPropertyBag\TargetKnownFolder   NAME NOT FOUND  Length: 144
3:01:16.1680023 PM  Explorer.EXE    2396    RegQueryKey HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{8DA1D365-1E63-4531-B1DD-824E76DD6F72}\Instance\InitPropertyBag SUCCESS Query: Name
3:01:16.1680236 PM  Explorer.EXE    2396    RegQueryKey HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{8DA1D365-1E63-4531-B1DD-824E76DD6F72}\Instance\InitPropertyBag SUCCESS Query: HandleTags, HandleTags: 0x0
3:01:16.1680427 PM  Explorer.EXE    2396    RegOpenKey  HKCR\CLSID\{8DA1D365-1E63-4531-B1DD-824E76DD6F72}\Instance\InitPropertyBag  NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Maximum Allowed
3:01:16.1680602 PM  Explorer.EXE    2396    RegQueryValue   HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{8DA1D365-1E63-4531-B1DD-824E76DD6F72}\Instance\InitPropertyBag\Target  SUCCESS Type: REG_SZ, Length: 24, Data: \\Client\D:
3:01:16.1680889 PM  Explorer.EXE    2396    RegQueryKey HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{8DA1D365-1E63-4531-B1DD-824E76DD6F72}\Instance\InitPropertyBag SUCCESS Query: Name
3:01:16.1681067 PM  Explorer.EXE    2396    RegQueryKey HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{8DA1D365-1E63-4531-B1DD-824E76DD6F72}\Instance\InitPropertyBag SUCCESS Query: HandleTags, HandleTags: 0x0
3:01:16.1681249 PM  Explorer.EXE    2396    RegOpenKey  HKCR\CLSID\{8DA1D365-1E63-4531-B1DD-824E76DD6F72}\Instance\InitPropertyBag  NAME NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Maximum Allowed
3:01:16.1681420 PM  Explorer.EXE    2396    RegQueryValue   HKCU\Software\Classes\CLSID\{8DA1D365-1E63-4531-B1DD-824E76DD6F72}\Instance\InitPropertyBag\Target  SUCCESS Type: REG_SZ, Length: 24, Data: \\Client\D:

3:01:24.9065880 PM  Explorer.EXE    2396    QueryDeviceInformationVolume    \\Client\D$\a.pdf   SUCCESS DeviceType: Disk, Characteristics: Remote, Removable
3:01:24.9066153 PM  Explorer.EXE    2396    FileSystemControl       \\Client\D$\a.pdf   NOT IMPLEMENTED Control: IOCTL_LMR_DISABLE_LOCAL_BUFFERING
3:01:24.9066404 PM  Explorer.EXE    2396    FileSystemControl       \\Client\D$\a.pdf   NOT IMPLEMENTED Control: FSCTL_LMR_QUERY_DEBUG_INFO
3:01:24.9068161 PM  Explorer.EXE    2396    QueryBasicInformationFile   \\Client\D$\a.pdf   SUCCESS CreationTime: 0, LastAccessTime: 0, LastWriteTime: 3/8/2018 3:01:18 PM, ChangeTime: 3/8/2018 3:01:18 PM, FileAttributes: A
3:01:24.9068310 PM  Explorer.EXE    2396    QueryStandardInformationFile    \\Client\D$\a.pdf   SUCCESS AllocationSize: 0, EndOfFile: 0, NumberOfLinks: 1, DeletePending: False, Directory: False

3:01:24.6940743 PM  Explorer.EXE    2396    CreateFile  \\Client\D$\a.pdf   SUCCESS Desired Access: Generic Read/Write, Write DAC, Disposition: Create, Options: Sequential Access, Non-Directory File, Attributes: A, ShareMode: None, AllocationSize: 57,092,249, OpenResult: Created
```

Comment: Monitor what explorer does by using Process Monitor. This should tell you the file path it's using. Maybe it's a totally different technology. Explorer uses MTP to copy to my Android phone for example.

Comment: It does have a drive letter, like all mounted flash drives.  It is D:  Consider using it.  .NET methods are forbidden from using native path names, they can't enforce FileIOPermission.  It is not terribly obvious to me why this doesn't generate the appropriate exception, might have something to do with long path support perhaps.

Comment: It's hard to understand the question; does the drive letter shown in the screenshot not work? Do you get some kind of error when you try to use it?